# Htaccess redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Previously our website was in aspx version and now we have revamped to php version.  We want to redirect

> http://www.example.com/index.apsx?sdsd=2

to

> example.com/

```
RewriteRule ^index\.aspx\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

We have used the above code but it's not properly redirecting. Its getting redirected to

> http://www.example.com/?sdsd=2

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.aspx/?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

With `?` at the end.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.